# Flutter: Using the iOS Promotional Offers

Tags: ios, flutter, subscription, discount

I am having some hard time trying to use iOS subscriptions promotional offers.
I was able to retrieve the discounts list from the productDetails after casting it to AppStoreProductDetails.

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
   List<SKProductDiscountWrapper> discounts = (productDetails as AppStoreProductDetails).skProduct.discounts;
}
```

However I have two problems

1 - discount object has no identifier, which makes it complicated to get a specific discount especially if a subscription has more than one offer

2 - How to apply the the discount when making the purchase?

```
_inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
```

PurchaseParam (also AppStorePurchaseParam) doesn't take discounts as params, where should we then use those discount objects?

any help or hint would be welcome. Thanks.